# This address: 127.0.0.1:5000 on Mac Catalina not working (docker) but working on Windows

Tags: macos, docker, port

This address: `127.0.0.1:5000` on Mac Catalina not working (docker) but working on Windows.

#### Question:

How do I get access to port:5000 working on my MAC?

```
# Host Database # # localhost is used to configure the loopback 
  interface # when the system is booting. Do not change this entry. 
## 
   127.0.0.1 localhost 
   255.255.255.255 broadcasthost 
   ::1 localhost 
# Added by Docker Desktop 
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the 
  container: 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal 
# End of section
```

Comment: Please paste the output of `cat /etc/hosts` from your Mac machine.

Comment: # Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

Comment: I would recommend to add this output in the description above (and format it as well) as it is not easy to understand it this way. Also can you try this - `http://localhost:5000` on the browser if this works or not.

Comment: Apologies - see above. Also the same error appears with i try: http://localhost:5000 (it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Update the line `## 127.0.0.1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Basically **#** is used for commenting in bash.

After that, you will be able to access using `127.0.0.1:5000` and `http://localhost:5000`